# Change the text alignment for Eureka TextRow

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am looking for a way to change the textField text alignment. I have tried it with

```
cell.textField.textAlignment = .Left
```

but that doesn't change the alignment. It will always stay right aligned. I was wondering why this was the default, as Apple themselves use left aligned text inputs in most, if not all places.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For Eureka is a little different. You have to use cell update callback. It wasn't well documented about changing alignment. But it did mention [here](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka#using-the-callbacks) that to change color or font you will have to use the `.cellUpdate.` Thus, i believe this work will work for you:

```
let row = TextRow() {
    row.title = "Field:"
}.cellUpdate { cell, row in
    cell.textField.textAlignment = .left
}
```